# Determine the default returned DialogCode for a QDialog with a QDialogButtonBox

Tags: qt, timer, countdown, countdowntimer, qdialog

I've created a custom dialog class inheriting from QDialog. I allow the user to call `exec(timeoutMs)` such that the dialog will automatically close after timeout. I'd like the dialog to finish rather than just close (which doesn't finish). Said differently, I'd like the dialog to return as if the default button was pushed if the timeout expires. Is there a good way to determine the default button and it's role in a QDialog? This is what I have now:

```
void MyDialog::timeout()
{
    int result = QDialog::Rejected;
    foreach (QAbstractButton *btn, buttonBox()->buttons()) {
        QPushButton *pbtn = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(btn);
        if (pbtn
                && pbtn->isDefault()
                && buttonBox()->buttonRole(btn) == QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole)
            result = QDialog::Accepted;
    }
    done(result);
}
```

Is there a better way?